# Unstack sorts my data frame

Tags: r, sorting

I have a data frame, `df`, which I have stacked and merged with another data frame, `info_df`.

I call it `Ta_stacked`

On the basis of `info_df` I sort my stacked data frame, by the column Progression.
After that I remove the columns from the `info_df`

```
sorted_stacked = arrange(Ta_stacked, Progression) %>%    
    select(gene_ekspression, sample) %>% drop_levels()
```

When I unstack my new sorted df, the sorting I did is overruled by unstacks alphabetically sorting.

```
sorted_df = unstack(sorted_stacked))
```

I have tried to use the `as.data.frame`:

```
sorted_df = as.data.frame(unstack(sorted_stacked))
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Here is pictures of my workflow, the matrices is just examples because I am working with a really big dataset.

[examples of datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cbi7.png)
[My workflow with unstacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9vHg.png)

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example (preferably using `dput`) and expected output.

Comment: I have added two pictures of my workflow.

Comment: Pictures are not reproducible. Use `dput` or include code to create toy data that reproduces your problem. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more details.